# How to catch moment when user was redirected to login page because of authorization cookie expiration ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, cookies, authorization, action-filter

Right now when authorization cookie has expired - user is redirected to default log on page.

I want to catch such moment and inform user in log on page that he was redirected because of time out.

I implemented custom AuthorizeAttribute:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute {
    public override void OnAuthorization( AuthorizationContext filterContext ) {
            var cookie = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
            var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);
            if (ticket.Expired) {
                //TODO redirect to Account/LogOn with some flag
```

But regardless of how cookie was set (persistent or not) it's null if is expired, and not null if not expired. Thus I can't reach moment when (ticket.Expired) because it's null at that moment.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] == null)
{
    Response.Redirect("login.aspx?expired=true");
}
```

And on the `login.aspx`-page:

In the `Page_Load`:

```
string expired = Request.QueryString["expired"].ToString();

if(expired == "true")
{
   //Show Message
}
```

Comment: If user comes first to site cookie is not set and in result he will see message - "You've been redirected to log on page because of  time out".

Answer (score 0):

Use `filterContext`:

```
var cookie = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

//not logged.
if (cookie == null) 
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary { { "area", "" }, { "controller", "Account" }, { "action", "LogOn" }, { "returnUri", filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl }});

FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = null;
ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);

//not logged.
if (ticket == null) 
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary { { "area", "" }, { "controller", "Account" }, { "action", "LogOn" }, { "returnUri", filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl }});

//logged, but expired.
if (ticket.Expiration > DateTime.Now) {
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary { { "area", "" }, { "controller", "Account" }, { "action", "LogOn" }, { "returnUri", filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl }, { "alert", "Session expired"} });
}
```

Comment: So, check if cookie is null, redirect, else not.

Comment: Read my comment to first answer, I explained why it not works. My problem is that when cookie is expired it's null, but it's also can be null because user has not been authorized yet, and will get same error message.

Comment: Do not you want user see that message in first enter site? If don't want - in your home action don't use CustomAuthorizeAttribute. If want - use CustomAuthorizeAttribute. Did I understand you right or not?

Comment: Nice idea, but most of the time users starts application not from home page, redirected to LogOn, and from there redirected back. It means if user comes first to CasesController which is marked with CustomAuthorizeAttribute they will be redirected to LogOn with message  they shouldn't see.

Comment: It is not unusual. It should be such. If user try to enter any action first time, he should redirect to logon page logically.

Comment: Such redirection is happening because of AuthorizeAttribute. If one user shares some resource (URL) to not logged in user OnAuthorization method is executed and and he's redirected to LogOn page, and that's logic I want to override only in case of auth token expiration.

Comment: It is meaning of AuthorizeAttribute. So, how you want it happen? Assume that, user first time try to enter any action. In this case what do you want to be happen? He should be redirect logon page

Comment: In this case I want regular redirect to LogOn, if that was auth token expiration - also redirect to LogOn but with special parameter to show user message that he was redirected because of session expiration.

Comment: Yeah it is clear now. So as I said above comment. Firstly check cookie is null or not. If yes, so user enter site just now. Redirect without parameter. Then check (ticket.Expired). In this case send any parameter.

Comment: Exactly, but if that would be so easy I wouldn't create question at stackoverflow: because if it already expired filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] returns NULL

Comment: If it expired cookie will be NULL! that's the problem.

Comment: I think this statement "if(ticket.Expired) {}" has any meaning. You can check user's logging is expired or user does not logon at all.

Comment: if (cookie == null) will be true when cookie expired

Comment: @Bohdan Sydor, if my answer did not work, I have other idea. Write a code around this logic: 
In layout wrhite a javascript code that check cookie in every 2 seconds for example. If cookie Expiration - DateTime.Now <= 2, then delete cookie and redirect user to logon.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found what was a problem, cookie is still available in Application_BeginRequest when it's expired but in Application_AuthenticateRequest it's already null (something is erasing it) so I'll put redirect logic into Application_BeginRequest